# How to prevent the recovery mode menu to come up!

Tags: autostart, recovery-mode

I arranged my system to power on due to any sudden power off and auto-start a program. The problem is that due to bad shut down sometimes a list comes up to use "Normal Mode" or "Recovery Mode" or "memtest, and it waits for the user to choose. It prevents my system to work whenever I'm not behind the system. How can I omit this menu or at least put a time counter to choose the first option "Normal Mode", just like Windows?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04,
Mainboard: MSI Z77A-GD65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recovery Mode in Ubuntu allows you to restore your system, change user passwords and gain root access to your Ubuntu machine in case of an emergency.

Open :

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

To disable it :

Uncomment :

```
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Save .

Update :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Now reboot if answer is correct don't forget to mark as answer

Comment: does it work for you ?

Comment: I rebooted the system. I didn't wait to have a bad shutdown or reset to see if the recovery menu come up, since #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true" says it's the answer. So, I marked it as answer.